# Fabulous glamour shot

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, internet

[image]

Found this picture on the web today. Being a lazy programmer, I don't want to actually open google and type a couple of characters. Way too much work! This is such an important task that it should be automated.

## Challenge

Everyone knows that the [first image](https://www.google.nl/search?q=codegolf&tbm=isch) in a google search result is always the best. Hence it should be presented to the user.

You are to write a program or function which takes a string as parameter and displays the first image it finds on google when you search for that name + the words `glamour shot` behind it.

## Google search queries

To search for images on google, the url should contain the query parameter [`tbm=isch`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/what-does-tbm-mean-in-google-search) and `q=query`, with `query` being the name you want to search for.
A valid query string for my name `Bas` would be `www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Bas`

## Input

Your program or function takes a single parameter of input, which is the name you want to search for on google. This string will consist of the characters `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]` and   (space). This string can be space seperated, to search for a space seperated string on google, one should replace the spaces with `+`. For example, this is a valid query:
[www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Bassdrop+Cumberwubwubwub+glamour+shot](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Bassdrop%20Cumberwubwubwub%20glamour%20shot)

## Output

The image can either be drawn to the screen, or saved to a file (in any format).
If the first search result on google is a gif file, you can either show the gif or show any frame of that gif.

## Test cases

Run this snippet to see the expected results

```html
<pre>f('Bas') // www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Bas+glamour+shot

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IViaM.jpg" style="width:40%;height:40%"/>

<pre>f('Bassdrop Cumberwubwubwub') // www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Bassdrop+Cumberwubwubwub+glamour+shot

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdhvW.png" style="width:40%;height:40%"/>
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: What characters need to be supported in the input? Do we need to worry about URL encoding?

Comment: @Martin Ender `[a-z0-9]`, edited my post. The urls will look like the examples I provided, no encoding needed, just space to `+`

Comment: I guess, `A-Z` can also appear, judging by your example?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, it's case insensitive. Forgot to mention

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub woops rookie mistake, I had indeed forgotten to escape the ampersand

Comment: There's a surprising number of people posing with guns when you play this game :D

Comment: What exactly counts as being drawn to the screen? Would navigating to the source location in IE or Chrome count as being drawn to the screen?

Comment: Can I get the thumbnail of the image rather than the image itself?

Comment: it is good you included the `search queries` restricts, otherwise one could just set up a custom short-url website which takes care of it.

Answer (score 8):

### PowerShell v4+, 160 bytes

```powershell
param($a)iwr (((iwr "google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=$($a-replace' ','+')+glamour+shot").links|?{$_.innerhtml-like"*$a*"})[0].innerhtml-split'"')[3] -outf "$a.jpg"
```

Takes input `$a` as a string. Does an `Invoke-WebRequest` (`iwr`) to the appropriate Google location, using inner-string script block to `-replace` spaces with `+` in the input string. We take the `.links` of that, where the `.innerhtml` is `-like` our input string. That yields the links with the proper thumbnail description. Take the first `[0]` one of those, take *its* `.innerhtml` and `-split` it on quotations. The fourth `[3]` element is the text inside the `img src="` portion, so we do another `iwr` on that, specifying `-outf`ile to be `$a.jpg` in the local folder. Since these are just the Google generated thumbnails, they're guaranteed to be jpg.

Comment: you can change out `google.com` with `google.nl` for -1 byte

Answer (score 4):

## Excel VBA ***+***, <sub><sub><s>465</s></sub></sub> 332 Bytes

> ***NOTE:*** Uses References to
>
> - Microsoft HTML Object Library
> - Microsoft Internet Controls
> - Microsoft Scripting Runtime

**Golfed:**

Full `Sub` routine that takes input `n` (short for name) of expected type `Variant/String` and outputs the first google image search result for the query of that name and `glamour shot` to an internet explorer window.

```vb
Sub g(n)
Set i=New InternetExplorer
l="google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q="&Replace(n," ","+")&"+glamour+shot"
For y=0To 2
i.navigate l
While i.readyState<4
DoEvents
Wend
j=0
Do Until InStr(1,l,IIf(y,"yp","res"))
j=j+1
Set x=i.document.getElementsByTagName(IIf(y,"img","a"))(j)
If y Then l=x.src Else l=x.href
Loop
Next
i.visible=1
End Sub
```

-2 bytes for removing white space in `If InStr(1, a.href, "imgres") Then`

-2 bytes for changing `.navigate (a.href)` to `.navigate a.href`

-27 bytes for reducing `for each a in ... if (...) then ... end if .. next` loop to `do until ... loop`

-10 bytes for condensing `imgres` to `res` and `encrypted` to `yp`

-8 bytes for removing initalizers for `j`, `k` and assuming clean module

-1 byte for changing `google.com` to `google.nl`

-3 bytes for replacing `Dim i as New ...` with `Set i=New ...`

-8 bytes for removing `SHDocVw.` class reference

-12 bytes for removing `with i` block

-7 bytes for removing `i.quit` - this causes some memory leakage by leaving internet explorer open in the background, as such it is recommended that either the full ungolfed version is used instead or that the internet explorer task is terminated through task manager after use

-6 bytes for moving `i.navigate` into helper subroutine `h`

-13 bytes for moving `Do Until ... Loop` into helper subroutine

-2 bytes by moving `j=0` into helper and removing `,j`, `,0` (x2)

-11 bytes for converting to an anonymous immediate window function

-8 bytes for reducing helper function calls into `for .. next` loop

-16 bytes for changing output from `Sheets(1)` picture object to displaying via the `InternetExplorer` object

**Ungolfed, 1304 Bytes**

```vb
Option Private Module
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub GlamourShot(ByVal name As String)

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, _
        doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, _
        link As String, _
        j As Integer, _
        k As Integer

    With ie
        On Error GoTo CloseIE #'prevents memory leak

        Let .visible = True
        Call .navigate("www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=" & _
                    Replace(name, " ", "+") & _
                    "+glamour+shot")
        While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            VBA.DoEvents
        Wend

        Set doc = .document

        Let j = 1
        Do Until InStr(1, link, "imgres") > 0
            Let link = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(j).href
            Let j = j + 1
        Loop

        Call .navigate(link)
        While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            VBA.DoEvents
        Wend

        Let k = 1
        Do Until InStr(1, link, "encrypted") > 0
            Let link = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(k).src
            Let k = k + 1
        Loop

        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            Call .Range("A1").Select
            Call .Pictures.Insert(link)
            Call .Activate
        End With
CloseIE:
        Call .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

**Usage gif**

[image: Usage Gif]

Answer (score 3):

## [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/), 30 keystrokes

```
pgi<End> glamour shot<CR>fi222jf<CR>fim2
```

Alternatively 27 keystrokes if you don't need the highest resolution image:

```
pgi<End> glamour shot<CR>fi222j;I<CR>
```

Video: https://youtu.be/t8824UjlYt8

Fortunately the standard search engine in Firefox is google, and Vimperator let you type hints by default. This is longer than it has to be to make sure that it always works regardless of what you search for.

Takes input through the clipboard.

#### Explanation:

```
p             Google the contents of the clipboard
gi            Select the search box
<End>         Move the cursor to the end of the text
 glamour shot Type " glamour shot"
<CR>          Press enter to search
fi2           Click the second link that begins with the letter "i" (images)
22j           Go 22 scroll steps down on the page.
              This makes it so that the first row of images are at
              the very top of the screen.

f<CR>         Click the first clickable element, which is the
              first image because we scrolled down

fim2          Click the second link containing "im" (view image)
```

Thanks to @TaylorScott for finding an edge case.

Comment: Does this handle cases when google recommends other search results as is the cases [such as this](http://imgur.com/a/gtTZG)

Comment: @TaylorScott It does not, but I am unable to get recommendations in Firefox. Could it be browser dependent?

Comment: Nevermind, I got them for a different search

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.6, <s>247</s> <s>242</s> 232 maybe 224 bytes

This is a cute attempt to solve this one. It will save a the file as `p.png` in the current directory.

```py
import sys; import requests as r; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as s;
n = sys.argv[1]; open('p.png', 'wb').write(r.get(s(r.get(f'https://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=isch&q={n}+glamour+shot').content,'lxml').find_all('img')[1].get('src')).content)
```

To run it with ease from the command line, just place the above content in a file, such as `glamour.py` and run:

```py
$ python glamour.py NAME_YOU_WANT
```

#### Update 1: Better version with new google url

```py
import sys; import requests as r; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as s;
n = sys.argv[1]; open('p.png', 'wb').write(r.get(s(r.get(f'http://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q={n}+glamour+shot').content,'lxml').find_all('img')[1].get('src')).content)
```

#### Update 2:

I saved a few bytes:

- By only importing the get function from the requests module
- taking advantage of the new python 3.6 string interpolation `f` flag without allocating the `sys.argv` to a variable
- eliminating some white spaces
- turning it into a one-liner
- removing the parser specification from the `BeautifulSoup` call

The last one is controversial, since it results in a std.output message telling the programmer to specify the parser for cross platform compatibility, so it might be considered unwanted output.

Here is the 224 bytes version:

```py
import sys;from requests import get;from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as s;open('p.png','wb').write(get(s(get(f'http://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q={sys.argv[1]}+glamour+shot').content).find_all('img')[1].get('src')).content)
```

Here is the 232 bytes version:

```py
import sys;from requests import get;from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as s;open('p.png','wb').write(get(s(get(f'http://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q={sys.argv[1]}+glamour+shot').content, 'lxml').find_all('img')[1].get('src')).content)
```

But the shorter version could be used if std.out is redirected to `/dev/null` or something :D

Comment: I could probably have a version with urllib + html.parse so that it can run entirely with the standard library.

Comment: you can likely use `www.google.nl/` or maybe even `google.nl` instead of `https://www.google.com.br/` to save some bytes

Comment: for some reason, I have to keep `http://` for it to work with requests. But the Brazilian google gave me funnier results, so I loose on fun points :D

Comment: Does this handle cases when google recommends other search results as is the cases such [as this](http://imgur.com/a/gtTZG) (you may have to do multiple searches to get suggestions like this to pop up)

Comment: I also love how I gain a few bytes thanks to the `n = 'something'; f'{n}_here'` instead of `n = 'something'; '{n}_here'.format(n = n)` or `n = 'something'; '{}_here'.format(n)`

Comment: @TaylorScott, i don't know. When I inspected the url for the first time, it had those headers, but I am not sure how they were introduced in the HTML response. Also the first element of the `BeautifulSoup` iterable where I retrieved all `img` tags was usually only garbage, so those headers might be there.

Comment: @Gui42The best way that I had to ensure that this handled the suggestions was to ensure that the link (src) for the final image contained `encrypted` (shortened for searching to `yp` based off of the possible domains)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59648/discussion-between-taylor-scott-and-gui42).

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 284 byes

```
(require net/url html-parsing sxml racket/draw)(define(g n)(let([g(compose get-pure-port string->url string-append)])(make-object bitmap%(g(car((sxpath"//*[@id='ires']//@src/text()")(html->xexp(g"http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q="(string-replace n" ""+")"+glamour+shot"))))))))
```

Screenshot: [image]